# Makefile: how to sed correctly to edit a variable

Tags: sed, pipe, make, echo

I'm trying to write a custom Makefile in which I collect all source files to compile against the main. First I collect their names:

```makefile
# other sources to compile against (without extensions, separated by spaces)
DEPENDENT_FILES = greet farewell
```

Then I'd like to append `.o` to each word. In a shell, I can do this in many ways, e.g.

```bsh
echo '$DEPENDENT_FILES' | sed 's/\>/\.o/g' # but I know, it's UNIX dependant
# or ...
echo '$DEPENDENT_FILES' | sed 's/[^ ]*/&\.o/g'
```

both result in `greet.o farewell.o` on the terminal, but fail (resulting in empty strings) during the `make` process.
I write them as

```makefile
DEPENDENCIES := $(echo '$DEPENDENT_FILES' | sed 's/\>/\.o/g')
# or ...
DEPENDENCIES := $(echo '$DEPENDENT_FILES' | sed 's/[^ ]*/&\.o/g')
# but they result in
$(info DEPENDENCIES is $(DEPENDENCIES)) # "DEPENDENCIES is "
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here, I suspect it could be something related to echos or pipes in Makefiles but I can't figure it out.

Please, I'd prefer answers related to working sed and echo solutions, without proposing different approaches: it's not the first time that I'm facing problems with echo and pipes in Makefiles and I still don't know what is wrong in my approach.

Comment: a note for anyone interested: if there is no dependencies, `/^$/!` can be written as prefix in the sed rule to avoid that an empty `$DEPENDENT_FILES` is translated to `.o` (e.g. `sed '/^$/!s/[^ ]*/&\.o/g')`

Comment: “Then I'd like to append .o to each word.” – You can do that directly in make using [the ``addsuffix`` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html). E. g. ``DEPENDENCIES = $(addsuffix .o, $(DEPENDENT_FILES))``.

Comment: Guess: Some of the quoting trips of because of make interpretation. Debug in the usual way by divide and conquer: first replace the whole `sed ...` part with `cat`, see if the pipe works. If it does, use `echo` instead of `sed` and no pipes to see what quotation make processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to realize that for all the similarities in their syntaxes, `make` and `shell` are quite apart and have to be used with abundant caution. To make matters worse, make is very stingy with its warnings.

You erred in two places in your `make` code:

```
## bad code 
DEPENDENCIES := $(echo '$DEPENDENT_FILES' | sed 's/\>/\.o/g')
```

- There is no `GNU make` built-in function named `echo l`, coz that is how make is understanding it to mean.
- What you need to do when you need to run an external utility is to call the gnu make built-in `$(shell ...)`  function.
- Now there's an insidious issue lurking in the way you wrote the make code, and that is the variable `$DEPENDENT_FILES`. make will parse it as a make variable $D followed by a string literal EPENDENT  ! This is coz make vars when not enclosed parentheses or braces are single letter only, rest being taken as literal string.
- Note shell vars vegin with $$  unless the eval is in play.

Comment: This is actually the answer that I've requested: very clarifying on my current mistakes

Comment: Please also note that `:=` is a make extension for target secific macro assignments, introduced by SunPro Make in  January 1986 and that later, GNU make introduced something completely incompatible, so be careful not to use `:=` in  portable makefiles.

Answer (score 2):

> Then I'd like to append .o to each word.

There is no need for the round trip through the shell. Make is powerful
enough to provide helpers for [common operations on file names](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html)
like this. In your case you want the function with the self-explanatory name
`addsuffix`:

```
DEPENDENCIES = $(addsuffix .o, $(DEPENDENT_FILES))
```

Which gets you `a.o b.o c.o` for an input list `a b c`. A more complete
example:

```
units = a b c

inc = $(addsuffix .h,$(units))
obj = $(addsuffix .o,$(units))

myprog: $(obj)
    gcc -o $@ $(obj)

header-bundle.h: $(inc)
    cat $< >$@
```

If you need more intricate substitutions, there’s also a variety of [generic
string operations](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html)
but where they are sufficient, the file ops are more convenient and IMO easier
to understand by a humble human.

Comment: Thank you, very clarifying and stylish. One only thing: what does `make header-bundle.h` should produce in this way? A single header with all the included dependencies?

Comment: The ``header-bundle.h`` was just an example of generating another file from the ``$(inc)`` generated list of header names. There are some projects that create a bundle of all public API headers compiled from individual files for convenience (or as a workaround for crappy compilers).