# AWK CUDA version command syntax error when starts from Makefile

Tags: awk, make, syntax

I have some issue I just want to catch exact CUDA version using nvidia-smi from command line and it is working in shell:
[image]

```
$ nvidia-smi | awk -F"CUDA Version:" 'NR==3{split($2,a," ");print a[1]}'
11.0
```

But when I am doing the same operation from makefile I have syntax error:

```
ver_cuda:
    CUDA = $(nvidia-smi | awk -F"CUDA Version:" 'NR==3{split($2,a," ");print a[1]}');
    VER_CUDA ?= $(CUDA);
```

Result:

```
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near ,
expr: syntax error: unexpected argument ‘11.0’
make: Nothing to be done for 'ver_cuda'
```

If somebody could help me I will be really apreciate !

Comment: Unfortunatelly issue still occured awk: line 1: syntax error at or near ,
expr: syntax error: unexpected argument ‘11.0’
CUDA = ;

Answer (score 4):

Part of the problem is that you're using `$(nvidia-smi ...)` instead of `$(shell nvidia-smi ...)`.   That's easily solved.

You also have to use `$$2` instead of just `$2` to prevent `make` from expanding it (probably expanding to nothing, resulting in the awk expression being just `{print }` and printing the entire line).

e.g. with a minimalist `Makefile`:

```
all:
    CUDA="$(shell nvidia-smi -q | awk -F': ' '/CUDA Version/ {print $$2}')"
```

Note the colon followed by space in awk's `-F` field separator.

```
$ make
CUDA="Not Found"
```

This is actually the correct value for my system, I don't have CUDA installed.

BTW, it's important to realise that while some make syntax looks a bit like shell syntax, it's very different....and, worse, the similarities can make it easy to write buggy makefiles.

See [Makefile: how to sed correctly to edit a variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/626649/7696) for a good answer relevant to your question.

---

On a more general note, you will probably find the output of `nvidia-smi -q` to be **much** easier to process with awk (or `sed` or `perl` or whatever).

e.g. on my system:

```
$ nvidia-smi -q | grep -i version
Driver Version                            : 460.56
CUDA Version                              : Not Found
    VBIOS Version                         : 86.06.0E.00.38
    Inforom Version
        Image Version                     : G001.0000.01.03

$ nvidia-smi -q | awk -F': ' '/CUDA Version/ {print $2}'
Not Found
```

I don't have CUDA stuff installed, so I just get "not found".  I can get a useful result for Driver Version:

```
$ nvidia-smi -q | awk -F': ' '/Driver Version/ {print $2}'
460.56
```

`nvidia-smi` also has various `--query-gpu` options.  e.g.

```
$ nvidia-smi --query-gpu=driver_version,vbios_version --format=csv
driver_version, vbios_version
460.56, 86.06.0E.00.38
```

Oddly, CUDA version isn't one of the `query-gpu` options.  See `nvidia-smi --help-query-gpu` for full details.

Comment: Thank you your solution works ! I used nvidia-smi -q | awk -F': ' '/CUDA Version/ {print $2}' I have some information about syntax but variable is assigned.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming GNU make:

Add the `shell` keyword before the `nvidia-smi` command and double the dollars in awk command. The similarities in make n shell syntax are a source of confusion.

```
ver_cuda:
    CUDA = $(shell nvidia-smi | awk -F"CUDA Version:" 'NR==3{split($$2,a," ");print a[1]}')
    VER_CUDA ?= $(CUDA)
```